# Wix conditional registry writing based on the user choice

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I use WiX 3.9 and WixUI_Advanced dialog to create a windows installer. The user has the possibility to choose to install the app locally or per machine (all users). For that i use the WixPerUserFolder property.

```
<Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerUserFolder" Order="1">!(wix.WixUISupportPerUser) AND NOT Privileged</Publish>

<Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="1" Order="8">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>

<Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="{}" Order="9">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>

<Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="ALLUSERS" Value="{}" Order="3">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>

<Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="ALLUSERS" Value="1" Order="2">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>

<Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[WixPerUserFolder]" Order="4">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>

<Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[WixPerMachineFolder]" Order="5">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>
```

Based on user choice (WixPerUserFolder or WixPerMachineFolder) i also want to be able to choose the registry key: HKCU or HKLM.

If the user selects for local installation then:

```
<RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="$(var.RegKey)" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes">
         <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
         <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="InstallDir" Value="[INSTALLDIR]"/>
</RegistryKey>
```

otherwise:

```
<RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="$(var.RegKey)" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes">
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="InstallDir" Value="[INSTALLDIR]"/>
</RegistryKey>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Root="HKMU"` will pick the right hive based on whether the package is run per-user or per-machine.